# MySQL explain shows 1 row in "rows" when there is no data in table at all

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `pk` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `index_col` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`pk`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;
```

no data in table at all.

And I have a query:

```
explain select * from test;
```

It shows in explain:

rows: 1

filtered: 100

From where does it get that 1 row, if there is no data in table at all?

Comment: Have you tried including database schema?

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL`, `EXPLAIN` returns execution plan of the query and not the actual result. This is what the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) says:

> When EXPLAIN is used with an explainable statement, MySQL displays
>   information from the optimizer about the statement execution plan.
>   That is, MySQL explains how it would process the statement, including
>   information about how tables are joined and in which order.

Execution plan is represented in a tabular format, and 1 `row` in the output is actually the row of the execution plan and not query output. This output shows 1 row per table and hence, if you have more than 1 table in your query, you will see 2 rows in the output regardless of the result of actual `SELECT` query.

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) the detailed explanation of `EXPLAIN` output format.

Comment: Ok, lets add 4 rows in the table: for example first 2 rows would have `index_col = 1` and last 2 rows `index_col = 2`. Then execute: `analyze table test;` to update statistics. Then let's execute explain again: `explain select * from test wher index_col = 1;` Explain says: `rows = 4`. But it should as I understand show 5 rows: 4 in table and 1 - execution plan itself. If I then add 2 more rows, analyze table again, and execute same query, explain will show `rows = 6` (not 7 - 6 from table and 1 as execution plan itself).

Comment: Ok, documentation says: `For InnoDB tables, this number is an estimate, and may not always be exact.`, I've changed table engine to MyISAM, truncated table, then reanalyzed table - explain shows `NULL` in `rows` - that's correct. I've added `2 rows` in MyISAM table, reanalyzed table - explain shows `2 rows` - that's also correct.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i've debugged mysqld source code and that what i've found out:

`n_rows = ib_table->stat_n_rows;` <- this is zero (if table is truncated what in my case is true or equals to rows count in table (but may be rows count in statistics of table)).

next below in the code

```
/*
The MySQL optimizer seems to assume in a left join that n_rows
is an accurate estimate if it is zero. Of course, it is not,
since we do not have any locks on the rows yet at this phase.
Since SHOW TABLE STATUS seems to call this function with the
HA_STATUS_TIME flag set, while the left join optimizer does not
set that flag, we add one to a zero value if the flag is not
set. That way SHOW TABLE STATUS will show the best estimate,
while the optimizer never sees the table empty.
However, if it is internal temporary table used by optimizer,
the count should be accurate */

if (n_rows == 0 && !(flag & HA_STATUS_TIME) <-- this expression is true
            && table_share->table_category != TABLE_CATEGORY_TEMPORARY) {
    n_rows++; <-- this code executes
}
```

then below

this value is used everywhere --> `stats.records = (ha_rows) n_rows;`

Comment: Good sleuthing.